# laravel update method ignores fields from hidden select

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a little form like this:

```
<form action="{{ url('equips') }}/{{$equip->id }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
{{ csrf_field() }}
{{ method_field('PATCH')}}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ $equip->name }}">
</div>
<div id="ex1" class="modal row selects col-md-9" style="background-color:transparent;">
  <div class="form-row col-sm-9">
    <div class="col">
    <label>Hud 1</label>
      <select id="w_hud1" name="w_hud1">
        <option>---Select---</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
      <i class="fa fa-btn fa-plus">update</i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

My update function:

```
public function update(Request $request, equip $equip)
 {
   $this->validate($request, [
       'name'       => 'required',
       'w_hud1'     => 'nullable'
   ]);
   $equip->update($request->all());
   return back();
 }
```

When I hit the update button the value of the select box won't be recognized by the update function - the var_dump of $request would be:

```
array(3) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "UFu6APAKP4gkyKFFxR7q6zTkPAFPSteLG0j7eU3u" ["_method"]=> string(5) "PATCH" ["name"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

But when I remove the "Modal" class from the div the value will be passed:

```
array(4) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "UFu6APAKP4gkyKFFxR7q6zTkPAFPSteLG0j7eU3u" ["_method"]=> string(5) "PATCH" ["name"]=> string(1) "1" ["w_hud1"]=> string(6) "203832" }
```

So it has something to do with the class.
Source of the class "Modal":

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.css

Any idea why this is happening? I hope I gave enough information.

Regards,

Andreas

EDIT: So it seems when I open the modal, change the selext option and close the modal the value won't be sent when I click on the update button.

Comment: Could you review the data sent in the browser inspect tool? This will show you what data is exactly sent to the server when sending the form.

Comment: Same data as I have posted earlier. Once the modal class is set none of the data from the form within the modal will be sent.

Comment: Does it work if you change the request from PATCH to POST?

Comment: `["w_hud1"]=> string(6) "203832"` does not appear in the HTML you've shown us - where does that value come from?

Comment: @Don't Panic. This will be filled by javascript.

Comment: @Adrian No, this will throw an methodnotallowed error.

Comment: OK, so there is more to the problem than we can see.  What is the final generated HTML, in both cases? Where is your JS?

Comment: Change it in both, route and blade code and see what you get

Comment: @Don't Panic. Will add the code in ~ 30 min,

Comment: In your markup, where is the closing `</form>` tag?

Comment: @Don't panic js content: https://pastebin.com/EgELZrBt

Comment: @Spholt just forgot to copy it to this question.

Comment: @Adrian my route is: Route::resource('equips', 'EquipmentController');